# Let $G$ be a graph and $\omega$ be its clique number

Tags: graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

I have been reading graph theory related to topological indices. 
I also found a question which is related to topological index (G.A. index) and clique number.

Let $G$ be a graph and $\omega$ be the clique number of the graph.
The G.A index [$(\sum_{I,j \in E(G)} \frac{2\sqrt {d_i d_j}}{d_i+d_j})$ where, $d_i$ and $d_j$ are the vertex degree]. then,

$G.A. \ge \frac {\omega (\omega -1)}{2}$.

Here the equality holds if and only iff G is the complete graph.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If we add to $G$ several isolated vertices, both $\omega(G)$ and G.A. will remain the same, so the claim about the equality should be corrected.